# Spring Java Config using Autowired caused NPE

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I am having difficulty understanding why something in Spring Java Config using `@Autowired` does not work.

First, I am trying to move all my `@Autowired` annotations in the Java Config classes.  This has the effect of making my "POJOs" back into real POJOs.  I can then not only test them easily outside of a Spring context, but can also use mock objects easily and readily.

So I first tried this:

```
@Configuration
public class Module3ConfigClass {

    @Autowired
    private Module1Bean1 module1Bean1;

    @Autowired
    private Module2Bean1 module2Bean1;

    @Bean
    public Module3Bean1 module3Bean1() {
        return new Module3Bean1(module1Bean1, module2Bean1);
    }
}
```

However, when the `Module3Bean1` constructor is invoked, both passed in Beans are null.  If you didn't follow my made up naming convention above, both of those beans would be created by a separate Java Config configuration file.  Also note that everything *is* wired up correctly - I know this because everything works perfectly when the `@Autowired` tags are on the corresponding private member fields inside of `Module3Bean1`.

FWIW, I tried adding an `@DependsOn` annotation to `module3Bean1()` method, but had the same results.   I guess I just would really like to understand this behavior, is it correct (I suspect it is, but why)?

Finally, I found an acceptable workaround shown here:

```
@Configuration
public class Module3ConfigClass {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public Module3Bean1 module3Bean1(Module1Bean1 module1Bean1, Module2Bean1 module2Bean1) {
        return new Module3Bean1(module1Bean1, module2Bean1);
    }
}
```

This seems fine to me, but if anyone would care to comment on it, that would be welcome as well.

Comment: Beans need to be created before they are autowired. Show us where those beans are, the other configuration. You would probably need to `@Import` that `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Well they are autowired correctly in two cases described above.  First is when the autowired is outside of the factory (configuration) process, and the second is when they are autowired in the code shown.  So just assume those are trivial beans each in their own (at)Configuration annotated class and imported correctly.  I am just wondering why some (at)Autowired beans show up in an (at)Configuration class and some (like shown above) do not.

Comment: Then I can only assume that all beans are created before they become eligible for injection/autowiring. As for your workaround, I think the method might be getting called twice, once for `@Bean` creation and once for `@Autowired`. Check your logs.

Comment: Thanks. The workaround you proviced to annotate the "@Bean" method with "@Autowired" also worked for me. I still don't understand why autowiring on java fields does not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you came across same problem I just had. In my case problem was invalid xml configuration. In my module B I had config like :

```
<beans>
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.moduleB"/>
      <import resource="classpath:applicationContext-moduleA.xml"/>
</beans>
```

In moduleA context I placed "context:annotation-config" annotation. 
When I change import/context order to :

```
<beans>
      <import resource="classpath:applicationContext-moduleA.xml"/>
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.moduleB"/>
</beans>
```

Autowiring for configuration class properties started to work.

Comment: Sorry I missed this reply way back when!  This is great information for others, but as I had no XML configuration and was pure Java Config, this does not answer the question (just telling you why I can't accept this as the question answer!)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and came to the conclusion that the error arose because we had a circular dependency where a `BeanPostProcessor` was involved.

- A PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (a BeanPostProcessor) has been configured to set its propertiesArray property with the help of another bean:

  ```
  <bean id="globalPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      lazy-init="false" depends-on="javaLoggingConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
          <list>
              <value>classpath:config/host/${env.instance}.properties</value>
              <value>WEB-INF/config/host/${env.instance}.properties</value>
          </list>
      </property>
      <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
      <property name="propertiesArray" value="#{springPropertyFinder.findProperties()}" />
  </bean>
  ```
- The used springPropertyFinder bean to set the propertiesArray is *not* a BeanPostProcessor but a "normal" bean that gathers all Properties instances with:

  ```
  public Properties[] findProperties() {
      Map<String, Properties> propertiesMap = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Properties.class);

      for (String title : propertiesMap.keySet()) {
          PropertiesLoggerUtil.logPropertiesContent(logger, "Springcontext Properties ("+title+")", propertiesMap.get(title));
      }

      return propertiesMap.values().toArray(new Properties[propertiesMap.size()]);
  }
  ```
- The @Configuration class contained a bean of type Properties

So our assumption is that the @Configuration class has been created without being processed by the ConfigurationClassPostProcessor (also a BeanPostProcessor), because the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer depends on the springPropertyFinder, which depends on the properties bean in the @Configuration class. The order of the BeanPostProcessors is probably not setup right under these circumstances.

This described setup worked in XML, but not with Java config.

Comment: This does seem very similar - @Autowired is also a post-processing step.  During the months since this post, we have also been able to confirm (or we think so) that it is a circular reference issue.  I suspect (albeit with no proof) that since Autowired was supported long before (2.5 I think) Java Config (3.x) came around there is a subtle issue buried in with sets of nested Configuration classes.